# Check if time exists in a Java string

Tags: java, regex, string, time, jsoup

I have a String variable which consists of some text with time in it.
example,

```
// string str looks like this
String str = "XYZ SuperMarket 10.00AM - 10.00PM"
```

1. Is there a way or lib which I can use to check if this string
   consists of time(Something like **Jsoup or Regex**)?
2. I want to trim the time content & store it in a different String named "**time**". Is it really possible to process strings this
   way.

Comment: That won't be a valid time. It is just an integer appened with a string. However, you can try to parse the string to a datetime.

Comment: Does the string format always stay the same?  Also, you need to consider that your string above contains two times.

Comment: You can capture with a regex and `Pattern.matcher(str).groupCount()` and `Matcher.group(int)` to get your times.

Comment: @LukePeterson Yes the string format will remain the same. Yes there are 2 timings - Start time & End Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm have no knowledge in Java programming and therefore cannot offer a Java code for this task.

But I can offer following regular expression:

```
((?:[01][0-9]|[0-9])(?:[.:][0-5][0-9]){0,2} ?[AP]M)
```

`(`...`)` at beginning and end of the entire expression mark the entire found string which might be needed to get the found string into a string variable.

`(?:[01][0-9]|[0-9])` is a non marking group for an OR expression. This OR expression finds either a number with 2 digits in range 00 to 19 or only a single digit in range 0 to 9. (Yes, numbers greater than 12 are also matched, but does that matter? I suppose, it does not. Keep it simple means make it fast.)

`(?:[.:][0-5][0-9]){0,2}` is a non marking group which is applied on the string to search 0, 1 or 2 times. It matches the minute and the second with the separator character between which can be either a dot or a colon. The minute/second must have 2 digits in range 00 to 59. (So this expression does not work for a leap second with has value 60, but I'm quite sure you have never seen a time with a leap second.) So the time string can be with just the hour, or with hour + minute, or with hour + minute + second. As I have never seen a time string with a single digit minute or second after an hour, the limitation on 2 digits minutes/seconds should not be a problem.

`?` matches a single space which could, but most not exist in time string.

`[AP]M` matches **AM** or **PM** as it looks like this is the time format you expect in the search string.

Note: There are dozens of different time formats. Therefore checking a string for all possible time formats would required lots of regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/rACIAu/1), `\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?\s*(?i)[AP]M\s*-\s*\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?\s*[AP]M` to retrieve the time slot from the text.

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `\d{1,2}`: One or two digits
- `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group

  - `[.:]`: One of the characters enclosed by the square brackets
  - `\d{1,2}`: One or two digits
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `?`: Makes the previous token (the non-capturing group in this case) optional
- `\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters
- `(?i)`: Makes the following token(s) case-insensitive
- `[AP]`: One of the characters enclosed by the square brackets
- `M`: Character literal, `M`
- `\s*`: Zero or more whitespace characters
- `-`: Character literal, `-`

The rest of the regex has things that have already been explained above.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String str = "XYZ SuperMarket 10.00AM - 10.00PM";
        System.out.println(getTimeSlot(str));
    }

    static String getTimeSlot(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern
                .compile("\\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\\d{1,2})?\\s*(?i)[AP]M\\s*-\\s*\\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\\d{1,2})?\\s*[AP]M")
                .matcher(str);
        String timeSlot = "";
        if (matcher.find()) {
            timeSlot = matcher.group();
        }
        return timeSlot;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
10.00AM - 10.00PM
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/WXyLia)